# odbc_execute fails on a prepared statement, then says it "failed to fetch error message"

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, ubuntu, odbc, freetds

Having this PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?";
$params = array('admin');
$result = odbc_prepare($link, $sql);
if (!$result) {
  die(odbc_errormsg());
}
else {
  if (!odbc_execute($result, $parameters)) {
    die(odbc_errormsg());
  }
}
```

I get this:

```
Warning: odbc_execute() [function.odbc-execute]: SQL error: Failed to fetch error message, SQL state HY000 in SQLExecute in [...]
```

However if I do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'admin'";
$params = array();
$result = odbc_prepare($link, $sql);
if (!$result) {
  die(odbc_errormsg());
}
else {
  if (!odbc_execute($result, $parameters)) {
    die(odbc_errormsg());
  }
}
```

I get the expected result. What could it be?

My code is running on Ubuntu Server, using UnixODBC and FreeTDS, connecting to a MSSQL Server 2008.

Regards!

Comment: I found that it appears FreeTDS doesn't support "Parameterized queries" (which I found incomprehensible): http://freetds.schemamania.org/faq.html#What.features.are.missing

Comment: Considering this is the top google hit for "SQL error: Failed to fetch error message" maybe we should come up with an answer that isn't "switch connection types"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the odbc_* functions why don't you use PDO? It should handle parameterized queries internally and pass along the SQL statement to the driver (FreeTDS in this case).